# find pip packages: pkg_resources specify custom target directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools, pkg-resources

Is there any way to specify a custom target directory for pkg_resources to list pip packages? I want to be able to find packages which have been installed in a custom target directory using `--target` through something like `pkg_resources.require()` that already fed with a custom target directory.

What I don't want is to use:

- `setuptools.find_packages` as it's only using `sys.path`
- `setuptools.PEP420PackageFinder.find`
- Finding packages through traversing the directory names and files was not helping as well, as I need a more generic way of finding package namespaces.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: isn't `pkg_resource.find_distributions('path/to/target/dir')` good enough?

Comment: Aah! Thank you so much, I wasn’t aware of this method! That does it

Comment: Nice, glad I could help!

Comment: If you post it as an answer it could help others as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

Python 3.8 introduced [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html), a module for querying the installed packages that supersedes `pkg_resources`. Example usage:

```
In [1]: from importlib import metadata
In [2]: dists = metadata.distributions(path=['my_target_dir'])
In [3]: list(f"{d.metadata['Name']}=={d.metadata['Version']}" for d in dists)
Out[22]: 
['pip==20.0.2',
 'ipython==7.13.0',
 ...
]
```

For Python 2.7 and Python >=3.5, there's a backport called [`importlib-metadata`](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/):

```
$ pip install importlib-metadata
```

#### Original answer

The `pkg_resources.find_distributions` function (documented under [Getting or Creating Distributions](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#getting-or-creating-distributions)) accepts a target dir to search for packages in. Example:

```
$ ls -l my_target_dir/
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 hoefling hoefling 4096 May 17 13:29 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 hoefling hoefling  126 May 17 13:29 easy_install.py
drwxr-xr-x 5 hoefling hoefling 4096 May 17 13:29 pip
drwxr-xr-x 2 hoefling hoefling 4096 May 17 13:29 pip-10.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 5 hoefling hoefling 4096 May 17 13:29 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x 6 hoefling hoefling 4096 May 17 13:29 setuptools
drwxr-xr-x 2 hoefling hoefling 4096 May 17 13:29 setuptools-39.1.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 5 hoefling hoefling 4096 May 17 13:29 wheel
drwxr-xr-x 2 hoefling hoefling 4096 May 17 13:29 wheel-0.31.1.dist-info
```

Scanning `my_target_dir` with `pkg_resources.find_distributions` yields:

```
In [2]: list(pkg_resources.find_distributions('my_target_dir'))
Out[2]:
[wheel 0.31.1 (/data/gentoo64/tmp/so-50380624/my_target_dir),
 setuptools 39.1.0 (/data/gentoo64/tmp/so-50380624/my_target_dir),
 pip 10.0.1 (/data/gentoo64/tmp/so-50380624/my_target_dir)]
```